# How relevant is WordNet nowadays?

Tags: computational-linguistics, semantics, lexical-semantics, tools, wordnet

How relevant is WordNet (both the original Princeton's and all other WordNets) as a tool for researchers now, decades later? 
Do researchers consider it valuable?

And does the general research community still actively work on improving individual WordNets (my faculty does)? Or do they consider it not worth the time? I mean, some WordNets have way more entries than others...

Thanks